# How do I run the OpenGrasp Robot Editor with Blender on Mac OS X?

Tags: python, blender, robotics

I'm using Mountain Lion at the moment.
I've installed Blender (because it's a dependency of OpenGrasp), and downloaded OpenGrasp. However, I try to load the robot editor up and I get this:

```
$ python GraspRobotEditor.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "GraspRobotEditor.py", line 34, in <module>
    import Blender
ImportError: No module named Blender
```

How do I point Python to the Blender python interface? the [Getting Started guide](http://opengrasp.sourceforge.net/robotEditor.html#getting-started) doesn't instruct you much here.

(I'm sure this is a trivial problem to solve but I'd like to see this documented on StackOverflow anyway.)

Answer (score 1):

From the error you it can't find the python module Blender which represents the python hook to Blender. So there could be a few This could be any number of reasons to do with your setup.

The first is that the Blender module is runtime generated whileBlender is running. The specific 'Blender' module used is part of the Blender 2.4x series. According to the link you provided there, they mention porting to newer versions but checking their snv the code is definitely written for 2.49.

Blender 2.49b was the last stable release - http://download.blender.org/release/ Ensure you are using that.

The next thing is whether it can be run via the the Run Script command

TL:DR

- Start up blender
- Switch to the text workspace
- Open the script and see if it can be run directly.

If not you will need to install the folder to the Blender modules directory of your install and then try running it.

Edit: Was looking at into the SVN some more and there does appear to be a version 2 for blender 2.5+ which can be put into a zip file and installed via the add-on installer. According to the bl_info it was build for 2.58 but what support level you would need to try out yourself.

Comment: Okay, hmm okay, I'll have a go at the add-on installer thing when I get time and let you know how I get on. Thanks.